# IOS How to make the view cover keyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, keyboard

I encounter the a problem:

I have a view controller like this.
[image]

TO make tool bar up when the keyboard appear, I move the self.view to up.

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + keyboardFrame.size.height * (up ? -1 : 1), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

Now I want to click the left button in the tool bar, and appear the view that frame is same as the this keyboard.

But where can I add this view?
if add the subview to the self.view, it will move up with the self.view on the top of the keyboard, not cover.
I'm a beginner about IOS, I have no idea about it, and have searched, but got nothing about this.

another question, IF when the toolbar at the bottom, I aslo want to click the left button on it to show the view(the animation and frame both are the same as the keyboard), how can I do ?

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: please update, if the answers are in the right or wrong directions. If yes please accept and rate.

Answer (score 1):

Am I right, that you want to pop the bar above the keyboard attached up and down with the keyboard?

Then you have to register to keyboard show and hide notifications and animate the view up and down based on the notifications and the keyboard show and hide speed.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

Now you have to implement all the selector methods:

```
//Code from Brett Schumann
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note{
    // get keyboard size and loctaion
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
    NSNumber *duration = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSNumber *curve = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];

    // Need to translate the bounds to account for rotation.
    keyboardBounds = [self.view convertRect:keyboardBounds toView:nil];

    // get a rect for the textView frame
    CGRect containerFrame = containerView.frame;
    containerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - (keyboardBounds.size.height + containerFrame.size.height);
    // animations settings
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[duration doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[curve intValue]];

    // set views with new info
    containerView.frame = containerFrame;

    // commit animations
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self showSendButton];
}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note{
    NSNumber *duration = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSNumber *curve = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];

    // get a rect for the textView frame
    CGRect containerFrame = containerView.frame;
    containerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - containerFrame.size.height;

    // animations settings
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[duration doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[curve intValue]];

    // set views with new info
    containerView.frame = containerFrame;

    // commit animations
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, containerView.frame.size.height-46.0f+20.0f, 0);
    _table.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _table.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    //display button based on facebook login status
    if ([facebookService.facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [commentButton makeButtonLogoutButton];
        textView.editable = YES;
    } else {
        [commentButton makeButtonLoginButton];
        textView.editable = NO;
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height+20.0f, 0.0);
    _table.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _table.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Surly replace the given view on top of the keyboard with your own view. This view should be a single view containing all the buttons and stuff.

Greetings

Comment: HI Fab1n, Maybe you misunderstand my problem, I have done the toolbar above the keyboard up and down. But I want another view, like the keyboard(the frame is same as keyboard), when it appear, it also up the toolbar, when it disappear, the toolbar also down to the toolbar.
The toolbar left button determined the view appear. or disappear.
Thanks your codes

Comment: ok then it is easy. Keyboard frame is always the same. There is one for Portrait and one for Landscape. You add this view at y-point 480 so it is initially hidden. When pushing the toolbar-button, just move the toolbar and your new view up the size of your new view. Use the animationWithDuration method.

Comment: Yes, and Thanks your advice and codes, it's very help for me.

Comment: @regrecall Why did you accept and then unaccept? Strange... Please explain!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you want to cover the keyboard? It looks like not the very good idea to do so. And I don't think it's even possible at all.
For the answer to your second question you should look at `UIView` documentation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    // place your view wherever you want
    CGRect frame = myView.frame;
    frame.y = self.view.frame.size.height - frame.size.height;
    myView.frame = frame;
}];
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, I want My View is frame is same as the frame of keyboard.
So, I must know the frame of the keyboard, I did it at the notification of the keyboardWillShown. So
before the keyboard appear, I can't do this.

Comment: Ok, understand. According to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) the keyboard sizes are constant for both layouts so I think you can hardcode this.